# Apply in English or in German?

Tags: applications, germany, cover-letter

I want to look for job in Germany but I have more than a B1 German level, so I can maintain conversations and write but not perfect. To apply I should do a CV and a motivation letter but I don't know if in English or German.

If I write the motivation letter in German and ask for help I will show a better level that the one I have, If I do it around my true level I will not do a good impression (The motivation letter is the first thing they see) and if I do it in Englsih maybe the reject me thinking that I do not have any german level.

This question is similar to: [Is it better to write a good cover letter in English or a mediocre one in the local language?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/is-it-better-to-write-a-good-cover-letter-in-english-or-a-mediocre-one-in-the-lo), but I want to ask more specifically about Germany and if the letter in German should be with a good level or my true level.

The answer there is to mix the languages in the letter (I dont think that is the best Idea) and with 2 letters I still have the problem if the German letter should be really good or at my true level

Comment: Which one are you the most fluent in?

Comment: I get that you do not like the selected answer but there are plenty of other answers on the question as well.  I have also added a bounty to that question so hopefully will get a few more answers to help you.

Comment: Is the job listing you want to apply for targeted for German speakers (i.e. it is written in German), or for non-German speakers (e.g. it is written in English and perhaps says "knowledge of German is an advantage")?

Answer (score 5):

Apply in the language that will be the everyday language for the role that you're applying for.

So if German is spoken in the office, apply in German.

If German is the main language and you apply in English, they will have little idea what your German skills are like.